# Custom Rails authentication / authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization

I know questions of this kind [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298/best-solution-for-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254/open-id-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901/strange-rails-authentication-issue) before, but my situation differs a little.

On my rails app I have to validate the user login against an existing repository and then control authorization to given modules. So, I don't want the solution I go for to generate a model for my users and rely on that. The authetication per se needs to be customized.

Under that scenario, what would be the best plugin to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether these will help, but I always use these links for reference apart from RESTful ACL

[1) http://clearcove.ca/blog/2008/08/recipe-restful-permissions-for-rails/](http://clearcove.ca/blog/2008/08/recipe-restful-permissions-for-rails/)

[2) http://steffenbartsch.com/blog/2008/08/rails-authorization-plugins/](http://steffenbartsch.com/blog/2008/08/rails-authorization-plugins/) - has a list of stuffs on authentication/authorization plugins

http://metautonomo.us/2008/09/30/easy-role-based-authorization/

Answer (score 2):

Look into [restful acl](http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/966-restful-acl)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one [secure_sessions](http://github.com/pliam/secure_sessions/tree/master), which makes no assumptions about your models.  Instead you provide a proc in your environment that is responsible for authentication:

```
SecureSessions::Password.validate_proc = proc do |ctrl| 
  # define any proc here which validates username/password etc, and returns a unique ID
  return nil unless User.authenticate(ctrl.params[:login], ctrl.params[:password])
  User.find_by_login(ctrl.params[:login]).id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Authority

I've just released a gem called [Authority](https://github.com/nathanl/authority) which is totally ORM-neutral; you can do whatever Ruby logic works for your app.

The original use case, for example, involved comparing roles described by a single-sign-on system with permissions in a YAML file.